# Connect to mySQL via GlassFish connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, glassfish

I'm having this error while trying to connect to mySQL database:

`No object bound to name java:comp/env/jdbc/mySql`

This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "org.onmyown.config" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.onmyown" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    try {
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context environmentContext = (Context)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource) environmentContext.lookup("jdbc/mySql");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
    HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
    return txManager;
}
}
```

I can ping from GlassFish just fine. I put all the properties I need (I think). My friend did this configuration with Derby database and it works. Is there any difference?

@edit

I 'fixed' something. I added web.xml, everything is here:

https://github.com/afterlook/SpringMVC

The problem now is that the application doesn't really care that i put mySql as a data source. It searches for DerbyPool which is one of the defaults in GlassFish. Any idea why?

Comment: read about [Context's Environment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/context.html), you must have set it before get it...  here is an [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/src/GetEnv.java)

Comment: I don't get it, are you trying to say that my properties that I return in hibernateProperties() are empty? If yes, then that's not the case. I have read these examples that you linked and I have no idea how is this supposed to help me. Let me also point out that I had my application working when I wasn't using connection pool with the code as it is. The only thing I changed was dataSource().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you posted originaly tries to use a datasource that is looked up using JNDI with the key comp/env/jdbc/mySql and this is not configured.

If you want to use a connection pool of Glasfish, you have to configure Glasfish so it creates that pool and publishes it as a JNDI component with the key comp/env/jdbc/mySql
[mysql glasfish](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html) shows how this is done.

With your fix you commented the JNDI code out, instead you set the connection url from a property.

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app
```

without additional configuration, this seems to point to the Glasfish default connection pool using the derby db.

If you want to use the Glasfish connection pool :

1. Configure Glasfish to crate that pool using mysql as described in the linked document.
2. You will configure url,user,password for the Glsfish connection pool, so I think you dont have to provide it in the spring config again. Take the datasource as you get it from the JNDI lookup.
3. Revert your fix that commented out the JNDI lookup.
   Your code should look like this :

   ```
    @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource() {
       DataSource dataSource = null;
       try {
           Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
           Context environmentContext =   (Context)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
           dataSource = (DataSource) environmentContext.lookup("jdbc/mySql");
       } catch (NamingException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }*/
       return dataSource;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. This documentation was a good starting point for my problem. I had a few minor problems on the way, but nothing that was too difficult to cope on my own. If somebody stumbles on the same problem, the repo is now up do date to lookup for changes.

Comment: And that fix was about web.xml. I was running my application with the JNDI lookup the whole time. I don't know why I commented it out before pushing to repo.